# Why does an Aperture smart album not select all the images with a keyword?

Tags: apple-aperture

With Aperture 3.4.5, when I show the list of keywords, it shows me a count of '58' images next to one of them. When I create a smart album that simply selects that keyword, it comes up with *8* images.

Where are the other 50 hiding?

Answer (score 2):

And the answer is: because some of them were sitting in the trash can.

Answer (score 1):

I just struggled with the same problem, and I came up with the following possible causes:

- Images are in the trash
- Images are rejected, and Aperture has a tendency to filter out rejected images.
- Images are in stacks, so if multiple images in one stack contain the keyword, only one is shown if stacks are collapsed.
- Images are located in the photostream, facebook, flickr, or other shared services (this took me quite some time to figure out)

The last part, images in shared services, also did give another symptom. When switching library, Aperture reported that my library contained approx 1150 versions. But if I opened 'Photos', there were only 700+ versions. So the last 400 were images located in photostream and on facebook, and some of the images in my photostream did contain keywords.